# Attaching entities to data contexts

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

In LINQ to SQL, is it possible to check to see if an entity is already part of the data context before trying to attach it?

A little context if it helps...

I have this code in my `global.asax` as a helper method.  Normally, between requests, this isn't a problem.  But right after signing in, this is getting called more than once, and the second time I end up trying to attach the `Member` object in the same unit of work where it was created.

```
private void CheckCurrentUser()
{
    if (!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        AppHelper.CurrentMember = null;
        return;
    }

    IUserService userService = new UserService();

    if (AppHelper.CurrentMember != null)
        userService.AttachExisting(AppHelper.CurrentMember);
    else
        AppHelper.CurrentMember = userService.GetMember(
            HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name,
            AppHelper.CurrentLocation);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there are two methods to do this.

```
DataContext.TableName.Contains(Item)
```

or we use the id field.  If the item is inserted in the Database, then it will be assigned a row.

```
if(Item.id == 0)
   DataContext.Insert(Item)
else
   DataContext.Update(Item)
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than attaching to a new data context why not just requery the object in the new datacontext? It believe it is a more reliable and stateless strategy.